# increase height of listbox in IE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

i have a listbox:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstProblems" runat="server" height=200px SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

and i am unable to size it in IE . IE just picks its own size.

how do i forcefully give it a specific height? if it is a CSS solution please spell it out for me since i do know how to work with CSS>

thanks so much for any guidance

at Andrew's request here is how the html gets generated: http://pastebin.com/HEdBg4f7

---

Here is an abbreviated version of the HTML around the `lstProblems` control. For some reason this control is given a height of 100% rather than 200px.

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Section B</legend>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="problemTextBox">Problem:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="problemTextBox" type="text" id="problemTextBox" size="50" /></dd>  
        </dl>     
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="lstProblems">Problems List:</label></dt>
            <dd>
               <select 
                  size="4" 
                  name="lstProblems" 
                  multiple="multiple" 
                  id="lstProblems" 
                  style="height:100%;"
              >
              </select>
            </dd>            
        </dl>  
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: I tried this on my own machine and it worked fine in IE9 set to IE7 compatibility. To improve the question, you could view the generate HTML and then copy and paste just the list box element's HTML to the question.

Comment: @andre thanks for the help! the html generated is exactly the same

Comment: @l__ - Don't just check the HTML - show it to us as well.

Comment: @andrew i edited the poste please see link http://pastebin.com/HEdBg4f7

Comment: @l__ I took the relevant HTML and added it to your question. Now we can ask the question: why is the height set to 100% rather than 200px? I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With asp.net and IE8, I had a similar problem. The browser displayed the listbox with the wrong height. The problem went away when I added a Font-Size property to the ListBox control. I set it at 1em.

```
<asp:ListBox ... Font-Size="1em" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you explicitly declared `height` using CSS?

```
#lstProblems{height:200px !important; display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: asp:ListBox is a server-side control. When the ASP.NET framework renders the page to HTML it renders the list box an HTML element with a newly generated a new client ID. (Which may or may not be "lstProblems"). For that reason, this particular CSS will not work.

Comment: I'm working in a ASP.NET environment. I'm dealing with this not lovely ecosystem everyday. It will render same ID if it's not inside a asp:panel. if it was in panel then the generated ID would be pandelID$elemID

Comment: @mohsen so you are saying that if i change it to regular HTML instead of asp then it will wrok