# asp.net getting list of items selected

Tags: asp.net, html

i have a combobox:

```
<select size="8" multiple="true" >
                <optgroup label="Europe">
                    <option>United Kingdom</option>
                    <option>Luxembourg</option>
                </optgroup>    
                <optgroup label="Asia">
                    <option>India</option>
                    <option>Dubai</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

i would like to know how i can return to the asp.net application which entries were selected by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A developer created a server-side control to do this: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/12/27/dropdownlist-with-optgroup.aspx

Try adding runat="server" and see what that gives you.  You should be able to access from the server some of its attributes, but I'm not sure how that all works with option groups.

As a last resort, if you have to, create an `<asp:HiddenField />` control and use JS to store the store the selections there.

HTH.

Comment: for this line:  ListItem item = this.Items[i]; i am getting this error: Error 48 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\WebForm1.aspx.cs 61 37 EnterData

Comment: for also this line :if (selected)
                                {
                                    this.VerifyMultiSelect();
                                } i am getting this error: Error 49 'EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1' does not contain a definition for 'VerifyMultiSelect' and no extension method 'VerifyMultiSelect' accepting a first argument of type 'EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\l

Comment: The link I provided, did you post this method on the page class?  This approach is a custom control.  create a new class that that inherits from dropdownlist, and put this method in there.

Comment: thank you very much. can you show me exactly how i can declare this new type of drop down? i was able to get no errors and now i am at this point  ListItem item = new ListItem("Group1", String.Empty);
            item.Attributes["optgroup"] = "optgroup";
            myDropDown.Items.Add(item);

Comment: im sorry but this is a dropdownlist i need a listbox or combobox

Comment: from what i understand this should have the functionality that i need but it is still a dropdown box. is it possible to make it a listbox

Comment: Probably ListBox would be fine.  They both work very similarly, although I'm sure you would have to adjust it.

Comment: so how would i get a list of selected items from it?

Comment: It inherits from ListControl I beleive, so it also has an Items collection of type ListItem

Comment: here is the question that i havent been able to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438286/increase-height-of-listbox-in-ie7

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3540/discussion-between-i-and-brian)