# how to i convert this asp.net list to html list?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

i have a list:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstProblems" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

and i am populating it this way:

```
$(function() {
        $.get('../file.txt', function(data) {
            var output = data.split('\n'),
            tmp = '';
            for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                tmp += '<option value=' + output[i] + '>' + output[i] + '</option>';
            }
            $('#lstProblems').html(tmp);

        });
    });
```

i would like to know how i can convert this to be a regular HTML list? i need this because of this question: [increase height of listbox in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438286/increase-height-of-listbox-in-ie7)

**update**
i changed the html to:

```
<select size="4" name="lstProblems" multiple="multiple" id="lstProblems" CssClass="list-problems">
```

and added this to css:

```
.list-problems {
    height:600px !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

neither IE nor chrome noticed a difference

could there be something overriding this?

here's everything that im including:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link href="../niceforms/niceforms-default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../niceforms/niceforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

here's the source from IE: http://pastebin.com/7vsF11Yq

Comment: according to your link in the original question, it's already a regular html list.  Just add `#lstProblems{height:200px !important; display:inline-block;}` to your css file

Comment: @joseph please see question edits,. thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Just add a class to the ASP.NET control and then use CSS as per the other question.*** 
The ASP.NET control will be rendered as a standard HTML list with a css class specified.

**So change your markup to**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstProblems" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="list-problems"></asp:ListBox>
```

**And then use the following CSS**

```
.list-problems {
    height:200px !important; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: i tried this .list-problems {
    height:200px !important;
    width:100px !important;
    display:inline-block;
} but it did not work

Comment: also tried to do this: .list-problems {
    height:600px !important;
    display:inline-block;
} and didnt work. perhaps there is something overriding?

Comment: @I__ Have you added the CssClas attribute to your `<asp:ListBox>`? Can you execute the page, then go View Source and paste the markup on http://pastebin.com ?

Comment: @marco also please see that i updated the quesiton thanks so much for your help

Comment: @I__ what CSS file did you append the `.list-problems {}` to?

Comment: @I__ hang on, something is not right looking at your markup. Adding CssClass to the ListBox should render the class as `class="list-problems` not `CssClass="list-problems"`. You don't need to add it directly to the `<select>` but instead the `<asp:ListBox>`

Comment: ok i changed it back to what it originally was (asp:listbox) and added the class and does not work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3542/discussion-between-i-and-marko)

Comment: <select size="4" name="ListBox2" multiple="multiple" id="ListBox2" class="list-problems">

</select>